# What is the Difference Between a Bound Method and a Function?

Tags: python, function, class, object, methods

Consider the following class:

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first=first;self.last=last
        self.pay=pay
        self.email=first.lower()+'.'+last.lower()+"@company.com"

    def fullname(self): return "{} {}".format(self.first, self.last)
```

if I access the fullname method like this:

```
em1.fullname #assume em1 object already exists
```

I get the following output:

```
<bound method Employee.fullname of <__main__.Employee object at 0x7ff7883acc88>>`
```

However, if I access the fullname method like this:

```
Employee.fullname
```

I get the following output: `<function Employee.fullname at 0x7ff7883c9268>`

Why are there two different definitions for the same function/method? I'm still accessing the same method/function object in memory, right?

Answer (score 2):

When you access `fullname` via an instance `em1.fullname`, you get a **bound method**, which means a version of `fullname` that automatically gets `em1` as its first argument.

So you can call `em1.fullname()` without having to pass any explicit argument. But if you called `Employee.fullname()` you would get an error because of the missing argument `self`.

This applies even when the method call is separated from the attribute access:

```
bound = em1.fullname
unbound = Employee.fullname

bound()       # OK, first argument is em1
unbound()     # Error, no argument for self
unbound(em1)  # OK, first argument supplied
```

Comment: What is the difference between `em1.fullname` and `em1.fullname()` then?

Comment: `em1.fullname` is a reference to the bound method. `em1.fullname()` is *calling* the bound method.

Comment: So `em1.fullname` is like a 'potential' function? It has all the parameters it needs to compute a return value, but it isn't asked to be called. Also, because it has the parameters it needs, it is fundamentally different from a function that doesn't have the parameters it needs?

Comment: `em1.fullname` is effectively a function that requires no arguments. `em1.fullname()` is a call to that function, which triggers a call to `Employee.fullname(em1)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm still accessing the same method/function object in memory, right?

Most definitely not, and it is apparent in the output you provided. The first lives at `0x7ff7883acc88` while the second at `0x7ff7883c9268`.

The first one belongs to an instance, while the second one belongs to the `Employee` class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the same function.

However, in order to call the function, with `em1.fullname` you just need:

```
em1.fullname()
```

But with `Employee.fullname`, you need to supply the `self` argument and you would need:

```
Employee.fullname(em1)
```